# GVim is slow at startup

Tags: vim

When I check vim startup with `gvim --startuptime gvim.log` I see:

```
15076.886  14652.943: starting GUI
```

This was built from ftp://ftp.vim.org/pub/vim/unix/vim-7.4.tar.bz2 on Ubuntu 12.04.
Dependencies installed with `apt-get build-dep vim-gnome`.

```
./configure --with-features=huge \
            --enable-gui=gnome2 \
            --enable-multibyte \
            --enable-xim \
            --with-x \
            --enable-rubyinterp=yes \
            --with-ruby-command=/usr/bin/ruby \
            --enable-perlinterp \
            --enable-pythoninterp=yes \
            --enable-python3interp=yes \
            --with-python-config-dir=/usr/lib/python2.7/config \
            --enable-fontset \
            --enable-cscope \
            --enable-gtk2-check \
            --enable-gnome-check
make
make install
```

Though `vim` and `gvim -u NONE` starts fast. Please help me troubleshooting this issue.

Comment: You can use `PPA` for `VIM` package. hope this link will be useful: http://askubuntu.com/questions/377436/daily-builds-for-vim

Comment: Are you running a binary you compiled yourself or the one you installed through apt-get?

Comment: I'm running the version that I compiled myself. It says `(2013 Aug 10, compiled May 17 2014 22:01:05) Compiled by ariunbayar@lt` within `gvim --version` output

Comment: Do you have any plugins installed? gvim -u NONE being fast makes me think that you have a plugin enabling an option that's making the gui run slowly.

Comment: Try `gvim --noplugin` to narrow the problem down to a plugin, or a problem in your vimrc.

Comment: + do you have a gvimrc?